# Field having an archimedean ordering and a non archimedean ordering

Tags: field-theory, ordered-fields

Let $F$ be a formally real field, so that $F$ has at least one ordering (compatible with the operations of $F$).

**Question.** is it possible for $F$ to have an archimedean ordering $\leq_1$ and a non-archimedean ordering $\leq_2$ ?

I know that the answer is NO in several cases:

- formally real number fields (because of the description of orderings of finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$)
- real closed fields (since such fields have a unique ordering).
- formally real pythagorean fields (pythagorean: every sum of two squares is a square), but the arguments I have are extremely complicated and indirect... To be quick, I think I can show that if $F$ is  pythagorean and admits an archimedean ordering , $SO_3(F)$ is a simple group, while if $F$ is pythagorean and admits a non archimedean ordering, I can show that $SO_3(F)$ is not a simple group.

I am pretty sure the answer is NO in general, but I cannot come up with simple arguments ( I am probably missing something obvious...)

If needed, I am mainly interested to have a simple proof in the case of formally real pythagorean fields.

**EDIT.** Apparently, there are fields $F$ for which the answer is YES (see GEdgar's comment).

The real question would then be:

**Question (V2).** Let $F$ be a formally real pythagorean field. Find a direct proof of the fact that $F$ cannot have an archimedean ordering $\leq_1$ and a non-archimedean ordering $\leq_2$.

Comment: Take $\mathbb Q$ together with one transcendental $x$.  Then the countable field $\mathbb Q(x)$ can be ordered (a) so that $x=\pi$, but it can also be ordered (b) so that $x>r$ for all $r \in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: @GEdgar That should be an answer.

Comment: @GEdgar, thanks! Would you have a simple explanation of the fact that this kind of things cannot happen if $F$ is pythagorean ?

Comment: It seems to me that the result you claim in the Pythagorean case cannot be correct: just take GEdgar's example but use the Pythagorean closure of $\mathbb{Q}(x)$ instead.

Comment: In particular, it does not seem true that $SO_3(F)$ has to be simple if $F$ is Pythagorean with an archimedean ordering.  I would imagine the natural geometric proofs require some intersections of circles at some point which need the field to be Euclidean, not just Pythagorean.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey if you use the pythagorean closure,,  can ensure to extend both orderings in such a way that the (non)archimedean property remains ?

Comment: @GreginGre: Yes: just take the real closure of either ordering, and then you can embed the Pythagorean closure inside that by taking the subfield generated by all square roots of sums of squares of elements of the original field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\mathbb Q$
together with one transcendental $$.
Then the countable field $\mathbb Q(x)$
can be ordered:
(a) so that $x=\pi$,
but it can also be ordered
(b) so that $ > r$ for all $r \in \mathbb Q$.